# dot net 6 fetching MongoDB not honoring the attribute "[JsonProperty]"

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core, system.text.json

I have some data in MongoDB and fetching it form there. 
The model is as below

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class Activity
{
  [DataMember(Name = "activitySource", EmitDefaultValue = false)]
  [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "activitySource")]
  public string ActivitySource { get; set; }
}
```

But when fetching data form there not data is return.

```
......
GetDatabase()
         .GetCollection<Activity>("Activity")
         .Find(x => x.ActivitySource == "....").FirstOrDefault();
```

But if I make that property in small it's working fine. (with or without attributes)

```
 public string activitySource { get; set; }
```

any suggestion

Comment: `JsonProperty` attribute is used by the Newtonsoft.Json for serialization/deserialization. Probably you mean `JsonPropertyName` for System.Text.Json. Aside, both attributes are not used by MongoDB .NET Driver. You should use the `BsonElement` attribute. `[BsonElement("activitySource")]`

Comment: Thanks @YongShun it working fin with that attribute.